# Pandas dataframe selecting with index and condition on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am trying for a while to solve this problem:

I have a daraframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A', 2, 3], ['B', 5, 6], ['C', 8, 9]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
j=[0,2]
```

But then when i try to select just a part of it filtering by a list of index and a condition on a column I get error...

```
df[df.loc[j]['a']=='A']
```

There is somenting wrong, but i don't get what is the problem here. Can you help me?

This is the error message:

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is filtered DataFrame compared by original, so indices are different, so error is raised.

You need compare filtered DataFrame:

```
df1 = df.loc[j]
print (df1)
   a  b  c
0  A  2  3
2  C  8  9

out = df1[df1['a']=='A']
print(out)
   a  b  c
0  A  2  3
```

Your solution is possible use with convert ndices of filtered mask by original indices by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandawheres.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
out = df[(df.loc[j, 'a']=='A').reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)]
print(out)
   a  b  c
0  A  2  3
```

Or nicer solution:

```
out = df[(df['a'] == 'A') & (df.index.isin(j))]
print(out)
   a  b  c
0  A  2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

A boolean array and the dataframe should be the same length. here your `df` length is 3 but  the boolean array `df.loc[j]['a']=='A'` length  is 2

You should do:

```
>>> df.loc[j][df.loc[j]['a']=='A']
   a  b  c
0  A  2  3
```

Comment: your solution is very nice!